# Infinite product space (TOPOLOGY)

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

> I am asking about the infinite product of $\{0,1\}$. That is, $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ is the space of all infinite sequence of $0_s$ and $1_s$, how collection of all finite sequences of $0_s$ and $1_s$ become a basis for its topology.

Why this is the case?

Comment: how was the product topology defined in your class?

Comment: @mm-aops it is said that the topology is generated by subbase $S=\{p_i^{-1}(U_i): U_i$ is open in $X_i\}$, where $p_i$ is the projection from the product space $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ to $X_i$.

Comment: there you go. and how does an open set $U_i$ in $X_i$ look like in your case? how does a finite intersection of $p_i^{-1}(U_i)$ look like?

Comment: @mm-aops Open sets in $X_i$ are $\emptyset ,X_i,\{0\},\{1\}$. For if $U_i=\{0\}$, then $p_i^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0\}\times \prod_{i\neq j} X_j$, and then I do not know how the result will look like after this step. I would be thankful if you type steps clearing this for me.

Comment: Layman, that's a good start! Next you are to apply the general recipe of going from a subbasis of a topology to a basis. Namely take the collection of all finite intersections of sets in the subbasis. What do those sets look like?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your comment. I think we will have something like this $\{0\}\times \{0\}\times \{1\} \times \prod_{i=4}^\infty X_i$. But where is finite sequences !!?

Comment: Remember that the "fixed" coordinates don't have to be consecutive. You also get sets where component 312 is fixed to be $0$, component 7777 is fixed to be $1$ and the rest can be chosen freely. Any finite set of positions can be fixed, and if the rest are freely chosen, together those sequences form a basic open set. There are no finite sequences in sight. Undoubtedly the poser of the question meant that fixing any finite subsequence leads to a basic open set.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For simplicity I have fixed the first 3 coordinates. I am sorry I do not understand your last two statements after "There are no finite sequenc .......".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let $p_n$ the projection onto the $n$-th coordinate. As you mention in the comments, a subbase for the topology on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is given by all sets $p_n^{-1}[O]$, where $O \subset \{0,1\}$ is open. Taking $O$ to be empty is pointless and taking $O = \{0,1\}$ is also pointless (as then the inverse image is just the whole space). So we only have to consider $O=\{0\}$ and $O = \{1\}$. So define $O(0, n) = p_n^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $O(1,n) = p_n^{-1}[\{1\}]$.

So $O(0,n)$ is the set of all infinite sequences of zeroes and ones that have a $0$ on the $n$-th coordinate, and similarly for $O(1,n)$ and $1$.

Now, if we have a finite sequence $a_0, a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is a finite sequence of zeroes and ones, then define $O(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n) = \cap_i O(a_i, i)$, so the set of sequences that agree with the finite sequence on the first coordinates. All these sets are in the base generated by the subbase, as finite intersections. And if we have any finite intersection $O(a_i, i)$ for some $i \in F$, $F$ a finite subset of coordinates, which contains some $(x_n)$, then $(x_n) \in O(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{\max(F)}) \subset \cap_{i \in F} O(a_i, i)$, so  the sets $O(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ (for all finite sequences) is a base for the product topology as well.

This is what is meant when we say the finite sequences form a base for the product: for every finite sequence $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$, the sets $O(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ (all infinite sequences that agree with the finite sequence in the beginning), form a convenient base for the product topology.

Comment: I got the answer from the above comments and your last paragraph. Thanks for all of you.